# Can someone explain what pixel field of view means?

Tags: field-of-view, pixels

I was wondering if someone could explain pixel field of view and how it relates to what parts of a scene a pixel may view. I understand that the field of view of a camera refers the total degree range in can see in either direction. However, I am confused as to what pixel field of view really means.

My understanding is that it is the degree range which every pixel can see in either direction. I also understand that the total field of view is the addition of all pixel field of views along each dimension. So if I want to think about what a specific pixel sees within it's field of view - wouldn't it just be one point in the scene? Or does it encompass more than that? Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Please give a link to where you have seen this term used.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a language translation issue, or perhaps you're just overthinking it. "Pixel field of view" isn't a common metric or phrase, but it just describes either:

1. the distance subtended, per pixel, at the plane of focus; or
2. the angular extent per pixel in the image.

Assuming a rectilinear (also call perspective projection) lens, in case #1, the total pixel extent of the image (say, horizontal) translates to a lateral measurement in the plane of focus. Taking a picture of a measuring tape across the width of a brick wall, you can easily see the measurement extent of the field of view, say, in meters. Knowing the number of horizontal pixels in the image, it's trivial to describe the pixel field of view of the image as "*x* meters per image pixel".

Similarly, in case #2, pixel field of view, in angular terms, is just the angular field of view per pixel (i.e., degrees, seconds, arcseonds, or fractions of them, per pixel). For example, the Hubble Space Telescope has an angular resolution of about 1/20 arcseconds. That's simply 1/20 arcsecond per pixel. Nothing more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

(We will have a circular description here. When I googled "pixel field of view" One of the first results was this question)

In my opinion, there is no such thing.

At first glance, it could mean that if you have a camera with a sensor with only 1 pixel, the pixel field of view would be that of the projection of the lens. Let's say **a°** =90°

But there are no sensors of 1 pixel, so let us simply divide that angle into the rows of pixels. In my image, I have 4 rows. 90°/4, right?
[image]

I quickly realized that this division does not work because the angular field of view of the pixels at the extremes **(b°)** differs from the pixels of the center **(c°)**.

That simple fact IMHO, ditches the idea of any practical usage of that term as a measure.

[image]

Add that to the fact that that angle is dependent on the focal length of the lens used.

[image]

So I don't think is a real practical concept. But using the words used on the term, I suppose that is what is referring to.